# I want to pass variables into my VBA with python yield using xlwings but doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

I'm trying to yield some variables from a python function to pass into my VBA code. But I couldn't seem to get it to work. The data is coming from a range name called rngTest.

[image]

Within my sub routine, I have the following code that calls a python function calls foo_func()

Python code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlwings as xw

def foo_func():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    rngTest = wb.sheets["Data"].range("rngTest").value

    for idx, test in enumerate(rngTest):
        i = str(idx + 3)
        yield i
        wb.sheets["Data"].range(f"F{i}").value = test
```

VBA Code

```
Sub Call_Python_Function()



    Dim x As String
    x = RunPython("import xlwings_test; xlwings_test.foo_func()")
    Debug.Print (x)

    Dim y As String
    y = "This is y"
    Debug.Print (y)

End Sub
```

I have also tried creating a UDF

```
@xw.func
def my_udf():

    for i in range(0, 10):
        yield i
```

VBA
    Sub Call_Python_Function()

```
    Dim x As String
    x = my_udf()
    Debug.Print (x)


End Sub
```

But getting this error since it's coming out as a generator object.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `RunPython`. You need to use User Defined Functions (UDFs) for that, see [the docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html). This is how you define a UDF in Python:

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.func
def double_sum(x, y):
    """Returns twice the sum of the two arguments"""
    return 2 * (x + y)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this but the getting another error when catching the variable back in VBA,  Objects of type generator, cannot be converted to a COM VARIANT

Comment: You can't use `yield`, use `return` instead.